# Extend "Merge from..." history in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image]Selecting "Merge from..." under the VCS menu, I can select a specific branch and then "Quick Manual Select" but the revision I need to merge is farther back than the list shows.  In the screen shot you can see I can't scroll down anymore, and there's not an option to go to older revisions that I can see.  Is there a way to get it to go back further and/or change the number of revisions it presents?

Comment: `Preferences` | `Version Control` | **Limit History by**? Try increasing this value and then refresh the revisions history in the Changes view so that more revisions are fetched from the SVN.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for the suggestion, but no joy.  I up'd it by 1000 rows and no change to that particular dialog.  The "show changed in last __ days" maxes out @ 31.